# How do you RESET the SQL Server 2008 TCP/IP Protocol settings back to default?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a SQL Server with multiple interfaces and a previous admin wanted to enable TCP/IP protocol to listen on a specific port.  I believe that wherever he saw a specific IP address, he replaced it with an alternative value and the custom TCP port we wanted to listen on for connections.

We are trying to troubleshoot an issue with a specific server not being able to connect remotely, and we THINK the issue may be with this SQL Server settings themselves.  **We specifically want to attempt RESETTING the Protocol configuration so we can start from scratch.**

Is there an easy way to do this within SQL Configuration manager or via query?  We do not want to reinstall SQL Server if at all possible.

Comment: How many IP addresses are you looking at?  There aren't that many parameters to configure.  Defaults are Active=Yes, Enabled=No, TCP Dynamic Ports=blank, TCP Port=1433.  It shouldn't take very long just using the Configuration Manager UI.

Comment: For default instances, what @squillman says is correct. For named instances, the SQL port is semi-random anyway so there's no "default" to put it back to.

Comment: @Mark good point about named instances, wasn't thinking about that